# How to write union value to an array element in C?

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, unions

I have an union like this -

```
union
{
  int a : 1 ;
  int b : 1 ;
  int c : 1 ;
} Byte1;
```

I am writing TRUE or FALSE to union members.

```
Byte1.a = x>0;
Byte1.b = y>0;
Byte1.c = z>0;
```

Whole content of union I need to write to an array element

```
int array[8];
array[7] = Byte1;
```

But this is throwing error - `incompatible types when assigning to type 'int' from type 'union'

How to assign union to array element in C?

Comment: `int array[7] = Byte1;`...what exactly you want?

Comment: There is something very wrong with basic syntax of `C`.

Comment: [Unions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) can only hold one value at a time so you are basically corrupting all data to set it all to `z>0`

Comment: As mentioned, I want to write value of union to array element

Comment: `int array[7] ` is not an **array element**. What you're upto?

Comment: Hi Sourav, sorry for wrong representation.. I want to write byte1 to 7th element of array.. (array is of int type)

Comment: Please don't use `int` bit-fields as they can be either signed or unsigned (yes!). Use `unsigned int a : 1` to store either 0 or 1.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use `union` and not `struct`?

Comment: Honestly, storing a boolean value in a variable called Byte but having a size of 4 bytes is... ehm... weird.

What's the use of using a union in this particular case, by the way? Did you mean to use a struct instead?

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> Whole content of union I need to write to an array element int
>   array[7] = Byte1;

But You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time. So whole contain is not possible to store. Store only one Required value in your array.  or you can do like this

```
array[7] = Byte1.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that your `union` can only hold int values (4 Byte) you could use `memcpy` to copy the data from `Byte1` to your array like so:

```
memcpy(array+7, &Byte1, sizeof(Byte1)); // copies the first 4 Bytes of Byte1 to array[7]
```

And don't forget to include string.h

```
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

While to copy **int**-sized **union**s to **int**s you may indeed use memcpy() as others mentioned, it is totally unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Let me try to describe in English what you do:

1. Have a 4-byte (or 8-byte, depending on architecture) storage.
2. Give it four different names (that is, a,b,c,d all refer to the same storage because of **union** keyword).
3. Modify the least significant bit of that storage based on some condition multiple times, each next time overwriting the previous value.
4. Copy the last result from the storage into some other storage

The following code yields the same effect with much less effort:

```
int Byte_that_is_actually_a_word;
...
Byte_that_is_actually_a_word = (z > 0);
...
int array[8];
array[7] = Byte_that_is_actually_a_word;
```

If instead you wanted to have 3 different boolean values stored in a single element of the resulting `array`, then you should have done it like this:

```
union {
    struct {
       unsigned int flag_x:1,
                    flag_y:1,
                    flag_z:1;
    };
    unsigned int all;
} bitmask;

...

bitmask.flag_x = (x > 0);
bitmask.flag_y = (y > 0);
bitmask.flag_z = (z > 0);

...

array[7] = bitmask.all;
```